# chrome window.load~ .play()

Tags: javascript, html

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("up").play();
    alert("k");
}
```

`<audio id="up" src="./res/up.mp3" loop="loop"></audio>`

hi I've just began studying html&js, and the code above worked fine on IE, but only the alert happened on chrome. Is this normal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because chrome throws an exception :

> DOMException: The element has no supported sources.

```
  "code": 9,
  "name": "NotSupportedError",
  "message": "The element has no supported sources."
```

Chrome has changed it's policy because `blocking roughly half of unwanted media autoplays`

READ : https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes

Reference :

> The Autoplay Policy launched in M66 Stable for audio and video
>   elements and is effectively blocking roughly half of unwanted media
>   autoplays in Chrome. For the Web Audio API, the autoplay policy will
>   launch in M70. This affects web games, some WebRTC applications, and
>   other web pages using audio features. Developers will need to update
>   their code to take advantage of the policy. More details can be found
>   in the Web Audio API section below.

```
Chrome's autoplay policies are simple:
```

- Muted autoplay is always allowed.
- Autoplay with sound is allowed if:

  - User has interacted with the domain (click, tap, etc.).
  - On desktop,the user's Media Engagement Index threshold has been crossed, 
    meaningthe user has previously play video with sound.
  - On mobile, the user has added the site to his or her home screen.
- Top frames 
   can delegate autoplay permission to their iframes to allow autoplay with 
   sound.

I have edited your code to display the error

```js
window.onload = function() {
    const playPromise = document.getElementById("up").play();
    // In browsers that don’t yet support this functionality,
    // playPromise won’t be defined.
    if (playPromise !== undefined) {
    playPromise.then(function() {
      // Automatic playback started!
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
       // Automatic playback failed.
       // Show a UI element to let the user manually start playback.
  });
}
    alert("k");
    
}
```

```html
<audio id="up" src="http://hcmaslov.d-real.sci-nnov.ru/public/mp3/Queen/Queen%20'Back%20Chat'.mp3" loop="loop"></audio>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a result of [Chrome's autoplay policy](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes), which restricts sites from playing audio before the user has interacted with the page.

Answer (score 0):

In summary **autoplay** in Chrome is **Not allowed** by default since april 2018. This to protect the user for undesired sounds. [More info](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes).

But, if the user interacts with the page (by making a click for example), then yes it is allowed, so you can change the onload code to a click. Like this:

```
window.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    document.getElementById("up").play();
    alert("k");
});
```

Click on the page, and walla.

Hope it helps.

Comment: you're welcome, Have you tried?, do you need any more help?